# Gitlab Pipeline getting skipped

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i am running my jobs on gitlab ci. I have a job which should run when i create a branch starting with test. I have used the below rule for it.

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^test/
```

But when i create branch no pipeline runs. It shows as status skipped.

[image]

Found the reason for the skipping.Suppose I am creating the branch from master. If the last commit on master was `commit: message [skip-ci]`. ie skipping ci. Then when branch is created from master the pipeline is skipped.
Is there anyway I could avoid this skipping on my test branch created from master

Comment: Can you provide some more details

Comment: Hi, what other details should i share. I thought only the rules part decides whether the job runs or not so that why shared it.

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve trigger of a job on branch creation. Why do you need it ?

Comment: can you check if you have a When: manual in this job?
If yes, then it is just waiting for the manual intervention.

This is an issue reported already for this by someone here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30075

Comment: can you include your entire CI file? Or at least anything global and the entire job? and also the name of the branch where you're seeing this issue?

Comment: No the skipped job is not a manual job.
I am seeing the issue with all branches starting with `test_`.
Could there be any case where even when i create a branch starting with `test_`
the value of CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME is not the branch name `test_`

Comment: i think i got the reason for pipeline getting skipped. Suppose i am creating the branch from master. If the last commit on master was commit: message [skip-ci].
ie skipping ci. Then when a branch is created from master pipeline is skipped.
I have updated the question.